# Expected maximum of a random vector

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

Is there an inequality of the following type:

$\mathbb{E}[\max\limits_{j<k}\{x_j\}]-\max\limits_{j<k}\{\mathbb{E}[x_j]\}\leq C(k)\sum\limits_{j<k}\sqrt{Var(x_j)}.$

Where $C(k)$ is a constant depending on $k$.
Note that $x_j,j<k$ can be any random variable (not necessarily independent).

Comment: I've put some thought into this and don't have an answer yet. My instinct was that it was false, but my counterexamples have failed. I'm curious: what's the context for this? Do you have any reason to suspect that such an inequality should / shouldn't exist?

Comment: I think it's true. Let $A_j$ denote the event that $x_j$ is the maximum (make sure $A_j,j<k$ are mutually disjoint). Suppose (without loss of generality) $\mathbb{E}[x_j] = \mu$ for all $j<k$. Let $a_j = \mathbb{E}[x_j|A_j]-\mu, b_j =\mu- \mathbb{E}[x_j|\overline{A}_j]$. $Var(x_j) \geq a_jb_j$. Then Express $\mathbb{E}[\max\{x_j\}]$ by $a_j,b_j$ will give a proof. Actually $C(k)=1/2$ and the equality holds implies $k=2$.